# Scikit-learn: overriding a class method in a classifier

Tags: python, oop, scikit-learn

I am trying to override the predict_proba method of a classifier class. The easiest approach as far as I have [seen](http://lgiordani.com/blog/2014/05/19/method-overriding-in-python) and if applicable is preprocessing the input to the base class method or postprocessing its output.

```
class RandomForestClassifierWrapper(RandomForestClassifier):

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        pre_process(X)
        ret = super(RandomForestClassifierWrapper, self).predict_proba(X)
        return post_process(ret)
```

However, what I want to do is copying a variable which is locally created in the base class method, processed and garbage-collected when the method returns. I am intending to process the intermediate result stored in this variable. Is there a straightforward way to do this without messing with the [base class internals](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bb39b49/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L478)?

Comment: what did you mean by "base classifier "?

Comment: I edited to avoid confusion.

Comment: @user36047 Which variable in `predict_proba()` are you trying to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overriding:

```
class RandomForestClassifierWrapper(RandomForestClassifier):

    def predict_proba(self, X):
            check_is_fitted(self, 'n_outputs_')

            # Check data
            X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr")

            # Assign chunk of trees to jobs
            n_jobs, n_trees, starts = _partition_estimators(self.n_estimators,
                                                            self.n_jobs)

            # Parallel loop
            all_proba = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,
                                 backend="threading")(

            # do something with all_proba

            return all_proba
```

Comment: I tried this first actually. Some errors appeared: The first one is NameError: global name 'check_is_fitted' is not defined

Comment: @user36047 add `from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted` the the top of your file

Comment: I got it working and I will accept this answer. I also edited the answer with the final working version of the snippet (edit: However, it seems not to have gotten thru peer review). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access local variables of a method from the outside. What you could do, since you have the code of the base classifier, is overwrite the `predict_proba` method by copying the code from the base classifier and handling the local variables however you want.

Comment: I tried this first. I was a little bit confused when errors began to appear.

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting? Do note that you'll need to use variables from the base class where the original just used `self.`.

Comment: If I override as in @OhAuth' s anwer, the first one is NameError: global name 'check_is_fitted' is not defined

Comment: Try changing that into `self.check_is_fitted('n_outputs_')`

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifierWrapper' object has no attribute 'check_is_fitted'.     RandomForestClassifier seems to inherit from a ForestClassifier which inherits from BaseForest and overrides its predict_proba